# Inserting Japanese characters to Sybase db from Excel

Tags: vba, unicode, sybase

I can see the Japanese test in the excel cells. I've built the insert query using ADO. It does the insert in the DB, but Japanese characters are simply represented as "????"
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the Sybase client where you are seeing the Japanse characters misrepresented? If you are lucky then it's just a mix-up between the server and a client. You can try running:

```
set char_convert off
```

in the Sybase client which will turn off Sybases automatic character conversion that it attempts to do.

If the above doesn't work then you have to find out what your Sybase servers default charset is. You can do this with:

```
sp_default_charset
```

This will return the default charset for your Sybase server (e.g roman8 ). Check the charset your server returns supports Japanese characters.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Paul. I could not write it in time in vba, so wrote the upload script in Perl instead :-(